# Dynamically modify matplotlib colorbar by indexing existing colormap

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, colorbar, colormap

I'm trying to create a zoomed in plot of the one shown below with a modified colorbar showing only the visible data series.
[image]
By modifying the x & y plot limits, I can ensure each line stays the same color.  Using the code snippet below, I can find an array of indexes for each data series which is visible inside the new axis limits (*buslist*), which I then use this to create a new colormap (*cmap_vals* -> *cmap_new*).  One [example](http://matplotlib.1069221.n5.nabble.com/get-colorlist-and-values-from-existing-matplotlib-colormaps-td23788.html) I stumbled across got me quite close to what I need but I can't work out why it's not mapping all the colors to the colorbar, as you can see in the last plot.  Note that the *buslist* array is **non-sequential** (ie #13 is missing from the zoomed in plot).

```
# Sort VUFmag array
ars = -np.sort(-VUFmag,axis=-1)*100

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6,4))                   # Create figure and axis tuple
x = 100*(np.arange(ars.shape[-1]))/ars.shape[-1]        # Define x-axis as % of time

n = len(ars)
cmap = plt.get_cmap('jet', n)

for i in range(ars.shape[0]):
   ax.plot(x,ars[i,:],color=cmap(i))       # Plot data

# Display limits
xlim=(-0.005,0.1)
ylim=(1.9,np.max(VUFmag*100)*1.05)

# Get bus numbers to be shown on colorbar
buslist = np.unique(np.nonzero(VUFmag > ylim[0]/100)[0])

#Get cmap values
cmap_vals = cmap(np.arange(n))[buslist]

# Define new cmap
cmap_new = matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('new_cmap', cmap_vals)
norm = matplotlib.colors.BoundaryNorm(np.arange(0,len(buslist)+1)-0.5, len(buslist))

# Define SM
sm = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=cmap_new, norm=norm)
sm.set_array([])

# Plot colorbar
clb = plt.colorbar(sm, ticks=np.arange(0,len(buslist)), pad=0.01)

# Set colorbar labels
clb.ax.set_yticklabels(buslist+1)
clb.set_label('Bus No.', labelpad=10)
```

Below is my current best attempt.  Any insights into what I'm missing here?
[image]

Comment: Why exactly do you want to change the colormap at all? It seems to me that the colors of the lines are unchanged, hence the colormap should stay unchanged as well and only the colorbar limits might be set the values needed to show the lines in the zoom.

Comment: I went down that path because my list of line/bus numbers is non-sequential (#13 is missing).  All the examples I found were trimming the colorbar limits at either/both ends but still leaving a sequential range of colors.  If I tried this method, is there a way to remove a single item from somewhere in the middle of the colorbar?

Comment: No, you cannot remove the item without there being a hole.

Comment: Using this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48962358/dynamically-modify-matplotlib-colorbar-by-indexing-existing-colormap?noredirect=1#comment84935298_48962358), I tried to 'grey' out the colorbar boundaries not shown on the zoomed in plot.  My new *cmap_vals* array looks correct but once again, the entire colorbar appears colored according to the first color only (ie the whole thing is grey)

Comment: Feel free to provide a [mcve], such that one can test.